# Humanizer fails to singularize or pluralize an italian word in C#

Tags: c#, cpu-word, pluralize, singular, humanizer

I have managed to singularize/pluralize an English word using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer), but
when I set the CultureInfo to Italian, it just adds an extra 's' to the word.

For example:

`"Man".Pluralize() => "Men"` ----- correct, It works as expected

`"Spaghetto".Pluralize() => "Spaghettos"` ----- wrong, It should be "Spaghetti"

I'm afraid it can't find the italian package `Humanizer.Core.it`, even though I have correctly installed everything!

Is this a bug or am I missing out something? If not, should I be writing my own set of rules and dictionary or is there another library I can use?

I'm currently working with .NET 4.x .

Thank you in advance, cheers!

Comment: Never new that Spaghetti does have a singular form. Does it work the other way arround (singularize spaghetti)?

Comment: No, if I try to singularize any Italian word it will just return an empty string! And yes, spaghetto is a legit word :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will come across words from time to time that do this, and you can of course just add to your own dictionary for Humanizer.

Declare this on your page.

```
using Humanizer.Inflections;
```

Then add your custom word to the vocabulary.

```
Vocabularies.Default.AddPlural("Spaghetto", "Spaghetti");
```

From here you can use the Pluralise on Spaghetto as much as you want, knowing you will always get Spaghetti.

Humanizer documentation for adding vocabulary found here:
https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#adding-words